# Mono gendarme equivalent for java

Tags: java, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

I'm looking for a source analytics tool that does an equivalent job to [Mono Gendarme](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/gendarme/) but for Java. Due to my current unfamiliarly with the Java universe I am not sure what the correct google search terminology would be and rather than go down the rabbit hole I'm hoping there are clear winners in this space.

Comment: seems that you are looking for findbugs: http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

You may look at:

- [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/)
- [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/)
- [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/)
- [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/)